# Connecting the UITextfield "clear" default button to a UILabel

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uilabel

Novice dev here. Sorry for what may be a dumb question, but is there a way to connect the circular 'x' button that can be enabled for the UITextfield object to a UILabel object, so that when a user presses the "clear" button in the textfield, the label clears as well?

I'm using a single-view application with only one view controller.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

The UITextFieldDelegate method [textFieldShouldClear:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldClear%3a) is called whenever a UITextField's clear button is pressed. Inside that method, you can execute any code you like, such as changing your UILabel's `text`.

Answer (score 0):

John Sauer's answer is good

but if you want change the label even if user delete the text not using clear button

you should use

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                                  withString:string];

    if ( newString.length == 0 )
    {
        //update label
    }


    return YES;
}
```